# Codeigniter - How to send API data via URL and get the response immediately without redirect and form action

Tags: php, xml, api, codeigniter, sms-gateway

Below is my code:

```
$sourceaddr = 14045; // Sender ID
$destinationaddr = 08887654657; // Destination Address
$shortmessage = "Hi, this is test"; // Message
$url = http://xyz.li/cdk; //Short URL
```

And I send above data via below URL (provided by SMS Broadcast API)

```
// API for sending SMS
$sent_url = 'http://username:password@ip:port/smsgateway/infobulk?sourceaddr='.$sourceaddr.'&destinationaddr='.$destinationaddr.'&shortmessage='.urlencode($shortmessage).' '.urlencode($url).'';
```

And If the message received (success) by destination address, I will get this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<message>
<TrxID>13349105571516524200</TrxID>
<Status>SENT</Status>
</message>
```

How to do that in Codeigniter way?

I have try using `redirect($sent_url)` but it doesn't get any response, 
It's a backend process, so I don't need any Form action, thank you.

Comment: I can't answer for codeigniter, but you're looking for it's curl functions, or even file_get_contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MODEL

```
class Sms_model extends CI_Model {

  var $source; //Source address
  var $dest; //Destination
  var $msg; // Message
  var $url;
  var $api_url;


  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function Send(){

    $this->api_url = 'http://username:password@ip:port/smsgateway/infobulk';
    $params = $this->source.'&destinationaddr='.$this>dest.'&shortmessage='.urlencode($this->msg).' '.urlencode($this->url).'';

    $post_data = array(
        "sourceaddr" => $params,
    );

    $stream_options = array(
        'http' => array(
           'method'  => 'POST',
        ),
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($stream_options);
    $response = file_get_contents($this->api_url, null, $context);

    return $response;
 }
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
class Sms extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function Index(){
    $this->load->model('Sms_model','sms_m');

    $this->sms_m->source = 14045 ;
    $this->sms_m->dest = 08887654657;
    $this->sms_m->msg = "Hi, this is test";
    $this->sms_m->url = 'http://xyz.li/cdk';

    $data = $this->sms_m->Send();

    print_r($data); 

   }
}
```

This will work on CI. Cheers.